# How to stop \label printing a reference number?

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

Is there a way to assign a reference to something (using `\label`), but to not actually have it show up in the document? I would still like to cross-reference it in a later part of the document?

For example, I have an counter called `\productitem`, and I'd like to do something like this:

`\productitem\label{initialitem}\\ %Lorem ipsum`

Then later in the document:

`\ref{initialitem} is sold...`

Now this code would print a reference number for `initialitem`, and then later on reference that number. However, I don't want the initial reference number to be printed, nor do I want any space given to it or any blank lines.

I realise you might wonder why I want to do this. I am producing a product listing; the initial product not available (or is not relevant to a particular listing) and so can't be listed. However, a variant of it does need to be listed. I would like to use the initial product's reference number as a basis for the variant's product number.

Comment: Could you please add a minimal compilable document that shows what you're doing (even if it doesn't work the way you want).  Especially because your question title doesn't make too much sense: `\label` itself never outputs anything, only `\ref` does.

Comment: Reading this question for the 5th time and I don't understand it...

Answer (score 2):

You can define a counter and let `\productitem` just `\refstepcounter` the counter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{productitem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\productitem}{\@bsphack\refstepcounter{productitem}\@esphack}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\productitem\label{initialitem}

See item \ref{initialitem}.

\end{document}
```

If the only use of `\productitem` is to set a new product and will *always* be followed by a `\label`, it's better (and more convenient) to set a macro to do both:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{productitem}
\newcommand{\productitem}{\refstepcounter{productitem}\label}

\begin{document}

\productitem{initialitem}

See item \ref{initialitem}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why \unskip and not \ignorespaces?  Just curious.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I wanted to treat it similar to how one would `\label`. I've updated it to do exactly that, taking it from [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co).

Comment: if used in this combination `\productitem\label{initialitem}`, the `\@bsphack/\@esphack` serves nothing special. It is done by `\label` itself to avoid double spaces in `foo \label{A} bar` situation. So `\refstepcounter{bbbb}\label{A}` is no different from `\label{A}` alone in that regard and needs no extra space hack.

Comment: @jfbu: Indeed. I don't know the use-case, but have added some more content.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious modification of the `\refstepcounter` command will set the current reference to the value of a given counter, without incrementing it; then `\label` can be issued as usual to capture the current reference value.  Here is an example of this technique:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\makeatletter

% Define core functionality:
\newcommand*\refbutnotstepcounter[1]{%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
        {\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}

\makeatother

% Define handy shortcut:
\newcommand*{\photocnt}[2]{%
    \refbutnotstepcounter{#1}\label{#2}%
}

% Test counter:
\newcounter{FOO}



\begin{document}

\setcounter{FOO}{123}\photocnt{FOO}{value-1}
\addtocounter{FOO}{300}\photocnt{FOO}{value-2}

The first value was $\ref{value-1}$, the second (and current) value is
$\ref{value-2}$.

\stepcounter{FOO}\photocnt{FOO}{value-3}
\setcounter{FOO}{-1}
In mid-paragraph \photocnt{FOO}{value-4} too.
\addtocounter{FOO}{100}\photocnt{FOO}{value-5}

We have now three more ``photographs'': $\ref{value-3}$, $\ref{value-4}$, and
$\ref{value-5}$.

\end{document}
```